# Considering Group and User to Install Apache httpd with different Directory - CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, rhel, software-installation, apache-httpd

I removed user and group related to apache, (preinstalled with apache from RPM).

I'm in the process of installing Apache HTTPD from binary source "tar.gz"

1. Download httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz
2. Extrat tar zxvf /.../httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
3. Create link `ln -s /usr/local/httpd-2.4.12 /usr/local/httpd`
4. Installed *apr-1.5.2.tar.gz* and *apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz* (because is needed)

Later, later

```
#./configure --prefix=/usr/local/httpd --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util
-with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --with-z=/usr/local/zlib
# make
# make install
```

So far there were no problems...

Later after editing `/usr/local/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and running the server `/usr/local/httpd/bin/apachectl`, it works perfectly...

---

Now, I want to create `user` and `group` for my Apache directory */usr/local/httpd*

**Question 1:**

Do I need a *system account*, e.g., `useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin apache`?

---

I want to put my html files in: `/usr/local/Html` (for example), editing in httpd.conf file *DocumentRoot* and *< Directory "usr/local/Html">*

**Question 2:**

What user must be used, *root* or *apache*, for my dirs:?

```
chown -hvR apache: /usr/local/httpd
chown -hvR apache: /usr/local/Html
```

---

**Question 3:**
What and how the permissions must be assigned to the owner with `chmod`?

```
chmod -R 750 /usr/local/Html
```

or

```
chmod -R 775 /usr/local/Html/
```

PS:  I was reading (Not strictly following)
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/apache.html

Thank you!

---

**I have problems!**

```
# useradd -g root -r -c "Apache User" -s /sbin/nologin apache
# chown -hvR apache:root /usr/local/httpd/
```

Using (there is no problem)

```
# /usr/local/httpd/bin/apachectl
#
```

but trying to use the recently created `apache` user, I have:

```
# /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh apache /usr/local/httpd/bin/apachectl start
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
#
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Answer**: Yes if you have deleted the user of apache that came up with rpm, you need to create on named as apache or www whatever, here -s /sbin/nologin apache indicate do not add the shell for apache user

   `useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin apache`

You can put your web files whatever you want **/srv/www**, **/var/www/** or **/usr/local/httpd** anywhere, but it must be defined in **httpd.conf**  file with DocumentRoot directiv and the web directory must have the appropriate ownership with the user **apache** and group of **root** aka

```
chown -R apache:root /srv/www
```

note: if you are running selinux in Centos and planning to put webfiles in  /var/www the selinux context must be labelled well for that directories , which can be done using below command

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/srv/www(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv /srv/www
```

you can verify by running **sesatus** command whether your system has selinux enabled or not, running selinux is considered as good security practice

2. **Answer**
   The user must be apache (your newly created user) with the group of root
3. **Answer** The permission mode of **755** OR **750** are  considered as idle for Linux web hosting

Comment: Hi thank you @user4820, 1) Using `useradd` the group is created implicitly, in this case the _apache_ group. I don't know what is the reason to _apache_ belong _root_ group. 2) In my scheme: `/usr/local/httpd` needs execution permissions and `/usr/local/Html` needs read, writte and delete permissions.